Forecast optimality for categorical dependent variable
I am familiar with several criteria of forecast optimality for variables on a ratio scale. E.g. Diebold Forecasting in Economics, Business, Finance and Beyond introduces the unforecastability principle on p. 334 and notes that many tests of aspects of optimality are based on it.

1-step-ahead errors, for example, had better be white noise, because otherwise we could forecast the errors using information readily available when the forecast is made. Indeed at least four key properties of optimal forecasts, which we can easily check, follow immediately from the unforecastability principle:
a. Optimal forecasts are unbiased
b. Optimal forecasts have 1-step-ahead errors that are white noise
c. Optimal forecasts have $h$-step-ahead errors that are at most MA($h-1$)
d. Optimal forecasts have $h$-step-ahead errors with variances that are nondecreasing in $h$ and that converge to the unconditional variance of the process.

Diebold then proceeds to discuss how each of the properties can be evaluated in practice.
I believe the unforecastability principle applies to forecasts of categorical variables (binary or multi-category) just as much as it applies to forecasts of variables on a ratio scale. However, I am not very familiar with its practical application. Thus my question:

What are the main optimality properties of categorical forecasts and how can they be evaluated in practice?

There are two settings under which we may be operating:

Forecasts are directly presented as point forecasts (class memberships).
Forecasts are based on estimates of class membership probabilities that are available to us, and we are interested in judging their optimality.

I am interested in optimality properties and their evaluation under both settings.
(If you think this makes the question too broad, let me know before voting to close it. I can split the question into two.)
I do not remember seeing this discussed in any textbook, and I would appreciate any references.
